# Ordenar lista com vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Ba tarde senhores, sou iniciante com vue e estou criando uma lista, mas estou com dificuldade para entender como irei ordenar lista clicando na coluna titulo segue exemplo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#lista",
  data:{
    users :[
      {nome: "Marcos Santos", email: "marcossantos@gmail.com"},
      {nome: "Lennon Bueno", email: "lennonsbueno@gmail.com"}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Vue 1</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="lista">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tr>
      <th><a href="#">Nome</a></th>
      <th><a href="#">Email</a></th>
     </tr>
     <tr v-for="item in users">
      <td>{{item.nome}}</td>
      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div> <!-- #lista -->
  </div> <!-- .container -->
  <script>
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Gostaria quando clicasse em nome ordenasse por nome, e por email ordenasse pelo email, por onde eu começo?

Comment: É só ordenar a array de dados. Sua dúvida é sobre como ordenar, ou sobre como rodar uma função (como a de ordenação) a partir de um clique?

Comment: @bfavaretto como rodar a ordenação a apartir do cllick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você começa pela método [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) que as arrays têm em JavaScript. Esse método retorna uma função onde você define como comparar um par de valores `a` e `b`. Ela deve retornar um valor menor que zero se `a` for menor que `b`, zero se forem iguais, ou um valor maior que zero se `a` for maior que `b`. E para comparar strings o método [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) convenientemente retorna um valor compatível com o `sort`.

Para amarrar um evento no Vue, basta usar os atributos [`@evento="..."`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input) (ou `v-on:evento="..."`) no elemento-alvo, e registrar o método a ser executado na lista de métodos do app ou componente.

No seu caso, pode fazer assim:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#lista",
  data:{
    users :[
      {nome: "Marcos Santos", email: "marcossantos@gmail.com"},
      {nome: "Lennon Bueno", email: "lennonsbueno@gmail.com"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    sortUsers: function(chave) {
      this.users.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[chave].localeCompare(b[chave])
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="lista">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th><a href="#" @click="sortUsers('nome')">Nome</a></th>
      <th><a href="#" @click="sortUsers('email')">Email</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="item in users">
      <td>{{item.nome}}</td>
      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div> <!-- #lista -->
```

Answer (score 4):

Conforme recomendação da documentação do Vue, utilize uma propriedade computed e a biblioteca [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). [Link da documentação](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter).

No exemplo, coloquei de acordo com a documentação, deixei comentado o código e também inseri um recurso adicional, o de inverter a ordem das colunas, exemplo de A-Z e Z-A.

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#lista",
    data: {
        // Coluna padrão para ordernar
        colunaSort: 'nome',

        // Opção de ascendente ou descendente, padrão inicia como asc
        colunaOrder: 'asc',

       // Itens para ordenar
        users: [
            {nome: "Marcos Santos", email: "marcossantos@gmail.com"},
            {nome: "Zeus Bueno", email: "lennonsbueno@gmail.com"}
        ]
    },
    methods: {

        // Metodo que define qual a coluna que será ordernada
        // Também define se é  ascendente ou descendente 
        sort: function(coluna) {

            // Se é a mesma coluna que está setando, então vai inverter a orderm de exibição
            if (this.colunaSort == coluna) {
                this.colunaOrder = (this.colunaOrder == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
            }

            // Se é uma coluna diferente, seta a coluna e define como ascendente          
            else
            {               
                this.colunaSort = coluna;
                this.colunaOrder = 'asc';
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        // Metódo que faz o sort das colunas, definindo o nome da coluna e a ordem
        orderedUsers: function() {
            return _.orderBy(this.users, this.colunaSort, this.colunaOrder)
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>

<div id="lista">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th><a v-on:click.prevent="sort('nome')">Nome</a></th>
      <th><a v-on:click.prevent="sort('email')">Email</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="item in orderedUsers">
      <td>{{item.nome}}</td>
      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito! de grande ajuda =)